# How to solve transient heat conduction equation at a point in space with volumetric heat source?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, optics, fluid

My system is a fluid exposed to light and I want to calculate the temperature change with time at a point, hence there are no spatial effects or convection due to the flow of the fluid.

The heat source is expressed as fluence multiplied by the absorption coefficient [W/cm<sup>3</sup>]. Given the same fluence, I want to see the effect of the absorption coefficient with time at a point in space.

What I have found similar is the lumped capacitance method and the equation is given by

$-hA (T-T_{inf}) = \rho V c \frac{dT}{dt}$

however, there is no internal heat generation and it considers boundary effects.

This leaves me with $Q = mc(T-T_{inf})$, and $Q$ is just energy.

Comment: What are the units on fluence $F$ and absorption coefficient $\alpha$ each by themselves? Is the net term $F\alpha$ having the units W/cm$^3$?

Comment: The unit of fluence is [W/cm^2] and the unit of absorption coefficient is [1/cm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picture a container with an area $A$ (m$^2$) and depth $d$ (m) holding a liquid. The container is perfectly insulated and the fluid is static. The fluid has a density $\rho$ (kg/m$^3$) and specific heat capacity $\tilde{C}_p$ (J/kg K). Both are constant. The fluid has an initial temperature $T_o$ (K). Irradiate with a fluence $F$ (W/m$^2$) on $A$ (m$^2$). The fluid has an absorption coefficient $\alpha$ (1/m). The light enters and passes through the fluid without being reflected at either boundary (input or output).

Assume that the input light energy that is absorbed by a volume of fluid causes an enthalpy change the volume of fluid.

$$(F A)(\alpha d) = \frac{dH}{dt} $$

Substituting $dH = \rho (A d) \tilde{C}_p dT$ for enthalpy and solving gives

$$T - T_o = \frac{F \alpha}{\rho \tilde{C}_p} \Delta t$$

The real system may have a larger volume of fluid than the light path. This happens for example when the light impinges on only a small portion of one bounding area. The resulting energy balance expressions will have to include forced / natural convective mixing. With an assumption that such mixing is instantaneous, one can write a simplified first approximation as

$$ T - T_o =  f_V \left(\frac{F \alpha}{\rho \tilde{C}_p}\right) \Delta t$$

where $f_V$ is the ratio of the volume of fluid through which the light travels to the total volume of fluid.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Do you have any material recommendations so I can read more about this? I never thought to take this approach.

Comment: The specific expression falls out from a global energy balance. A starting point might be a textbook on basic energy balances over systems.

Comment: Noted with thanks, I will look into that. 

Alternatively, can I add a heat source term in the lumped capacitance method?

Comment: What you present as a lumped capacitance method equates a convection flow input (left side) against an enthalpy change in the fluid. Just replace the convection input term by the light energy input term.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a real world system, its temperature should not rise at a constant rate forever. Instead it will try to achieve some kind of an equilibrium. For a fluid with mass $m$, capacity $c_p$, constant light energy input $\alpha F$, environment temperature $T_{env}$ and heat transfer coefficient with the environment $U$, this equation should apply:

$$m c_p \frac{dT}{dt} = \alpha F + \left(T_{env}-T(t)\right) U$$

Assuming only the fluid temperature will change in time, you can separate the variables and integrate both sides using starting fluid temperature $T_0$:

$$\int\limits_{T_0}^{T}\frac{1}{T-T_{env}-\frac{\alpha F}{U}} dT = -\frac{U}{m c_p}\int\limits_0^{t}dt$$

Resulting expression for fluid temperature $T$ as a function of time $t$ should look something like this:

$$T(t) = T_{env}+\frac{\alpha F}{U} + \left(T_0-\frac{\alpha F}{U}-T_{env}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{U}{m c_p}t\right)$$

From this you can see that at the start $t=0$, the temperature $T(t=0)=T_0$ because the exponential is 1 and other terms cancel out. Equilibrium is reached in infinity, $T(t\rightarrow \infty)=T_{env}+\frac{\alpha F}{U}$ as the exponential term goes to 0. It is a typical exponential function where you have the highest rate of temperature change at the start and it will decrease in time as the system approaches equilibrium.
[image]